# Let's Encrypt certifcate for MS CRM using IIS

Tags: lets-encrypt, iis-8.5, microsoft-dynamics-crm, crm

I am installing an instance of MS CRM 2015 on-premise, on a Win 2012 R2 Server, IIS 8.5.

I would like to use the Let's Encrypt service to generate certificates for crm.example.com on this server.

Let's Encrypt would like to use the `.well-known/acme-challenge` directory for validation. MS CRM has taken over the Default website and redirects requests to its website folder, using Windows authentication.

**Is there a way to whitelist the `.well-known/acme-challenge` folder** within the CRM website, so as to avoid authentication?

I have tried adding a `location` section in the `web.config`, but IIS throws an error because the path starts with a dot.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config

I have tried adding a handler to solve that problem, as in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis 
but I get the same error there.

As an alternative, Let's Encrypt can be validated using DNS, but I am not really up to that, and I can't find evidence that my provider has an API for that purpose.

**Do I have any other options?**

Comment: "*so as to avoid authentication?*" you mean "to avoid redirection", right?

Comment: Have you tried using `<location path="Default Web Site/.well-known">` in ApplicationHost.config rather than web.config, that seem to work for me

Comment: @Peter, good suggestion. I can change the authentication settings from `<location path="Microsoft Dynamics CRM/.well-known">` in ApplicatonHost.config (beware editing with 32 bit editor). I still get a 401 for extensionless files.

Comment: @techraf, I am learning something of the innards of CRM, but I am not too sure about the actual page serving and authentication sequence. What I know is that the default response for the site is to show an authentication pop-up that I don't want for the ACME challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Peter Hahndorf for the workaround, to @benadams [letsencrypt fixes for IIS](https://github.com/ebekker/ACMESharp/issues/15%20ACME%20sharp%20wiki) for the syntax, and to @Mike Ratcliffe [(editing ApplicatonHost.config)](http://www.beacontechnologies.com/blog/2014/06/why-are-changes-to-my-applicaionhost-config-not-showing-up-in-iis/)

If you want Let's Encrypt to write to a ./well-known subfolder of CRM website, create the subfolder first and the change the configuration as follows.

Edit the  `ApplicationHost.config` (the main IIS config fil), mine was under  `Windows/System32/inetsrv/config`. If you are running a 64-bit edition of Windows, you must use a 64-bit editor (I used Windows Notepad).

I added/changed the following lines in the `<location path="Microsoft Dynamics CRM/.well-known">` section.

`<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <staticContent>
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="text/plain" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type=""    modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
        </handlers>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>`

This allows anonymous authentication and any user access to a path starting with a dot, under the CRM default website.

With this setup I could request a certificate using letsencrypt-win-simple
PowerShell script.